# Nginx rewrites taking precedence over redirects?

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I have some redirects set up in an include file for our nginx config. I noticed the other day that some redirects aren't working, and they seem to just be the ones that are impacted by rewrite rules.

Can anyone take a look and see what I've done wrong? Here are the relevant snippets:

/etc/nginx/sites-available/MySite.conf:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com ;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/includes/Redirects.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/includes/Rewrites.conf;
    ...
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/includes/Redirects.conf:

```
#This redirect works:
location ~ ^/images/products/1234.jpg { return 301 /images/products/5678.jpg$is_args$args ; }
#This redirect does NOT work
location ~ ^/p/1234 { return 301 /p/5678$is_args$args ; }
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/includes/Rewrites.conf:

```
#This rewrites the short URL /p/<ProductCode> to our ecommerce system's default URL
#I think this is what is conflicting with the redirect above
rewrite ^/p/(.*) /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=$1 break;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be clear from the documentation, but `rewrite` directives in the `server` block are evaluated sequentially **before** the search for a `location` to process the URI.

So the "`rewrite ^/p/(.*) ...`" statement will be evaluated before the "`location ~ ^/p/1234 ...`" statement, irrespective of the order of these two statements.

You could convert your `rewrite` statements into `location` blocks or vice versa.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/p/1234 /p/5678 permanent;
rewrite ^/p/(.*) /mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Product_Code=$1 break;
```

Comment: I switched the `location` style redirects to `rewrite` as you suggested and it worked perfectly - thanks!